# Как достать параметр из файла конфигурации

Tags: c#

Есть файл конфигурации в xml.
так он выглядит

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="WatersInterop.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="ELNInteract.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="Modules" value="" />
    <add key="NewVersionServer" value="" />
    <add key="EnableDiagnosticActions" value="False" />
    <add key="Languages" value="ru-RU;ru" />
  </appSettings>

  <applicationSettings>
    <ELNInteract.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="ElnInternal" serializeAs="String">
        <value>C:\Program Files (x86)\WATERS\NuGenesis LMS\Waters.ELN.Toolkit.ClientIntern.dll</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="ElnExternal" serializeAs="String">
        <value>C:\Program Files (x86)\WATERS\NuGenesis LMS\Waters.ELN.Toolkit.ClientHelper.dll</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="ElnHelper" serializeAs="String">
        <value>C:\Program Files (x86)\WATERS\NuGenesis LMS\Waters.ELN.Toolkit.ClientExtern.dll</value>
      </setting>
    </ELNInteract.Properties.Settings>
    <WatersInterop.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="WatersInterop_ExternalDB_ExternalDBServiceService"
          serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://localhost:8180/ExternalDBApp-war/ExternalDBService</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="WatersInterop_ExternalDBOld_ExternalDBServiceService"
          serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://localhost:8070/ExternalDBApp-war/ExternalDBService</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="DecimalSep"
                  serializeAs="String">
        <value>,</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="ProtectSheet"
                  serializeAs="String">
        <value>false</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="SampleplaceCalibr"
                  serializeAs="String">
        <value>false</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="OldServer"
                  serializeAs="String">
        <value>false</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="adddataname"
                  serializeAs="String">
        <value>ADDDATA</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="NeedDebugInfo"
                  serializeAs="String">
        <value>false</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="UseSamplesStatusesWorkFlow"
          serializeAs="String">
        <value>false</value>
      </setting>
    </WatersInterop.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>

  <connectionStrings>

    <!--
    Use the following connection string to connect to a Jet (Microsoft Access) database:
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Password=;User ID=Admin;Data Source=Solution9.mdb;Mode=Share Deny None;"/>
    -->
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <switches>
      <!-- Use the one of predefined values: 0-Off, 1-Errors, 2-Warnings, 3-Info, 4-Verbose. The default value is 3. -->
      <add name="eXpressAppFramework" value="3"/>
      <!--
      <add name="XPO" value="3" />
      -->
    </switches>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Как  мне достать этот параметр `name="WatersInterop_ExternalDB_ExternalDBServiceService`

Пробовал стандартно, типа String SERV = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[]; 
Но как то не достает параметр.

Answer (score 2):

Если решать в лоб, то можно так:

```
string path = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None).FilePath; 
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
string attributeNameToSearch = "WatersInterop_ExternalDBOld_ExternalDBServiceService";
var applicationSettings = doc.Descendants("applicationSettings");
var watersSettings = applicationSettings.Descendants("WatersInterop.Properties.Settings");
var result = watersSettings.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(s => s.Attribute("name") != null && s.Attribute("name").Value == attributeNameToSearch);
```

Но лучше использовать наследников классов `ConfigurationElement`, `ConfigurationElementCollection`, `ConfigurationSection`, Подробнее [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/128517/) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316058/how-to-create-custom-config-section-in-app-config)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я такой вариант пробовал, но прием очень полезен. Я думал, есть более лаконичное решение